# I'm trying to get sum of digits from a number, Where Is the Mistake?

Tags: c#

```
        int Number = 12;
        int Sum = 0;
        string sNumber = Convert.ToString(Number);
        for(int i = 0; i < sNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            Sum = Sum + Convert.ToInt32(sNumber[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(Sum);
```

it should show 3, But instead its showing 99.
What is actual mistake.

Comment: sNumber[i] will not return 1 or 2

Comment: accessing a string via indexer returns a _character_. when converting a character to an integer, you get the _internal representation_, in your case 49 and 50, instead of the parsed content.

Answer (score 2):

If you iterate the characters in a string, you'll get chars. The problem is that converting a `char` to an `int` with `Convert.ToInt32()`, will result in the <strike>ASCII</strike> **Unicode UTF-16** value of that char.

The <strike>ASCII</strike> **Unicode UTF-16** value of '1' = 49 and for '2' is 50 which sums 99.

You should make it a string first.

```
int Number = 12;
int Sum = 0;
string sNumber = Convert.ToString(Number);
for(int i = 0; i < sNumber.Length; i++)
{
    Sum = Sum + Convert.ToInt32(sNumber[i].ToString());
}
Console.WriteLine(Sum);
```

Comment: convert to string and then to int is not required.

Comment: @AmitVerma true, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: yes, but approach is also very important.

Comment: Thanks for Explaining Mr. Langen.

Comment: FYI Convert.ToInt32 gets the UTF-16 value of the character. Granted, for OPs question these are essentially the same but it is a subtle difference as a char may represent any UTF-16 value.

Comment: That's more accurate, I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Convert.ToInt32(sNumber[i])` is getting the numeric value of the character at position `i`, i.e. `Convert.ToInt32('1')` gives 49. Note that this value is a `char` and therefore `Convert.ToInt32('1')` returns the value of the UTF-16 character.

Why convert it to a string when plain mathematics will do what you want.

```
int number = 12;
int sum = 0;

while (number > 0){
    sum += number % 10;
    number /= 10; // Integer division
}

Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to the following:

```
        int Number = 12;
        int Sum = 0;
        string sNumber = Convert.ToString(Number);
        for (int i = 0; i < sNumber.Length; i++)
        {
            Sum = Sum + Convert.ToInt32(sNumber.Substring(i,1));

        }
        Console.WriteLine(Sum);
```

Use `Substring` instead of `[]`
`Convert.ToInt32(char x)` will give you the UTF16 value of the char.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=net-5.0#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToNumber(char)` returns code of character in ASCII. In your example `1` have code 49 and `2` have code 50. 49 + 50 results in 99

You need to use `Sum = Sum + int.Parse(sNumber[i].ToString())` to get actual value of digit

Comment: .Net characters are UTF-16 not ASCII

Answer (score 0):

no need to convert to string for this. Use simple mathematics.

```
int Number = 123;
            int Sum = 0;

            while (Number != 0)
            {
                Sum += (Number % 10);
                Number = Number / 10;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(Sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it hasn't been posted, here's a simple one-liner using Linq:

```
int Sum = Number.ToString().Sum(x => (int)char.GetNumericValue(x));
```